# use jquery to insert 'rel' attribute in <a> tag

Tags: jquery

I'll preface this by saying that I'm a total jquery newbie.  That said, I'd like to use jquery to insert a 'rel' attribute with a value of "shadowbox" into the `<a>` tag in the following bit of code...

```
<div class="bibImage" title="">
<a href="" target="_parent"><img src="" border="0" alt=""></a>
</div>
```

This is system-generated html, so I don't have the option of adding 'class' or 'id' attributes which would help jquery target the element.  The div is uniquely identified, so I'm guessing that it's possible to specify the `<a>` as a child(?); but I'm really not sure how.  Nor do I understand which method can be used to actually insert the 'rel' attribute + value.

Thanks in advance for any insight and guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(function() { // this signifies when the DOM is ready
   $('.bibImage a').attr('rel', 'shadowbox'); // this will add it to 
                                              // all <a> inside the <div>
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   $('.bibImage a').attr('rel', 'shadowbox');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.bibImage a:first-child').attr('rel', 'shadowbox');
```